# Point sets and limit points.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, limits

Show that if M is a point set having a limit point, then M contains at least
2 points. Must M contain 3 points? 4 points?

Having difficulty describing and visualizing, because it seems rather obvious.

Comment: Well, it must contain at least countably infinitely many points...

Comment: I'm not sure your claim is true @Vim. You might have to assume you are working in a metrizable topological space for that to be true.

Comment: @PatrickJ.Dynes yes I'm talking about metric space.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the following: let $S$ be a subset of a topological space $X$. Then a point $x$ in $X$ is called a limit point of $S$ if every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point in $S$ distinct from $x$.

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $U$ be an open set containing a limit point $x $ of $X$. Then, since $U$ is a neighborhood of a limit point $x$ of $X$, it must contain a point in $X$ distinct from $x$. Thus $U$ contains at least two points.

In general, we cannot guarantee that that $U$ contains more than $2$ points. For example, consider the topological space $X = \{0,1\}$ with the indiscrete topology.